# Setting PathAnnotation on SSIS path from code

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been trying lately to create SSIS packages from .NET code rather than using drag and drop in Visual Studio. As part of the package documentation, I would like to be able to annotate data flow paths.

The code below - copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136086.aspx) - establishes a path between two SSIS data flow components. By adding

```
    path.Name = "My name";
    new Application().SaveToSqlServer(package, null, "localhost", "myUser", "myPassword");
```

I can set the name of the path to whatever I like and then save the package in my local SQL Server. When I open the package in Visual Studio 2008, however, the name of the path can only be seen under path properties.

In Visual Studio, there is another path property, PathAnnotation, with the value AsNeeded and additional possibilities SourceName, PathName, Never. Changing the value to PathName gives me what I want: The path name appears next to the path in the data flow tab in Visual Studio.

My question is: Is it possible to set the value of the PathAnnotation property from code?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Samples
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Package package = new Package();
      Executable e = package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
      TaskHost thMainPipe = e as TaskHost;
      MainPipe dataFlowTask = thMainPipe.InnerObject as MainPipe;

      // Create the source component.  
      IDTSComponentMetaData100 source =
        dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
      source.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbSource";
      CManagedComponentWrapper srcDesignTime = source.Instantiate();
      srcDesignTime.ProvideComponentProperties();

      // Create the destination component.
      IDTSComponentMetaData100 destination =
        dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
      destination.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbDestination";
      CManagedComponentWrapper destDesignTime = destination.Instantiate();
      destDesignTime.ProvideComponentProperties();

      // Create the path.
      IDTSPath100 path = dataFlowTask.PathCollection.New();
      path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(source.OutputCollection[0],
        destination.InputCollection[0]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in getting an answer in a different forum. Please see

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/23e6a43f-911f-44da-8e69-cd9e53d7e5ed